# Removing visible lines between merged Sentinel-2 L2A tiles

Tags: qgis, merge, sentinel-2

My project area is covered by 4 different S2A MSIL2A tile but when I merge those different tiles on QGIS I can see visible lines between them as shown below.

[image: TILES WITHOUT ANNOTATION]

- TILE 1: S2A_MSIL2A_20201115T080211_N0214_R035_T38SKJ_20201115T120134
- TILE 1: S2A_MSIL2A_20201115T080211_N0214_R035_T38SKH_20201115T120134
- TILE 3: S2A_MSIL2A_20201115T080211_N0214_R035_T38SLJ_20201115T120134
- TILE 4: S2A_MSIL2A_20201115T080211_N0214_R035_T38SLH_20201115T120134

[image: TILES WITH ANNOTATION]

How can I remove those lines? With my limited knowledge I couldn't find a way to do it, do I need to apply any correction, if so there is any guidelines I can find on Internet?

Comment: Search with keywords "histogram matching". Not many open source tools are good at it. OSSIM probably can do it.